# Координаты линии при рисовании

Tags: c#

Я не совсем пойму, почему параметр y задает координаты центра линии, а не верхнего левого угла?
Ниже пример кода и результат

```
int x1 = label1.Location.X + label1.Width;
int x2 = x1 + label1.Width;
int y = label1.Location.Y;
e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 13), x1, y, x2,y);
```

[image]

Comment: Y-координаты концов отрезка совпадают с Y-координатой лейбла. В чем проблема?

Comment: Потому что линия -- "линейный" объект: если вы поменяете ширину линии (то есть, `Pen`), линия логически должна остаться на том же месте. И потом, почему вы хотите именно верхний левый, а не нижний левый угол? Как несчастной линии догадаться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ответ:** потому, что это наиболее логично - рисовать линию, используя начальную точку и ширину.

Если Вы хотите опустить на один уровень, лучше используйте заполненный прямоугольник или вычтите половину высоты label.